# transferring output to the list

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

How do I transfer the output from the following code:

> “It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”
>   “There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”
>   “The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”

to a list like version?

> [[“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”],
>   [“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”],
>   [“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”]]

This is my code:

```
from random import choice,sample
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
page = 1
response = requests.get('http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/'+ str(page))
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
articles = soup.find_all(class_="quote")
for a in articles:
    list_of_quotes = []
    data = a.find(class_="text")
    quotes = data.get_text()
    list_of_quotes.append(quotes)
    data1 = a.find(class_="author")
    author = data1.get_text()
    data3 = a.find('a')
    href = data3['href']
    print(quotes)`from random import choice,sample
```

Comment: And what is the problem you encounter?

Comment: Does the inner list represent anything, i.e. do you need to change `quotes = data.get_text()` to return you a list potentially containing more than one item (e.g. by splitting on an HTML tag inside the data block)? Or can you just put quotes in a list as you append it?

Comment: `list_of_quotes = [a.find(class_="text").get_text() for a in articles]` is this what you're looking for?

Comment: yes i just trying to pull up the list and use it with random sample for quiz

Comment: Oh, so you just need `["a", "b", "c"]`, i.e. a list, and not specifically `[["a"]. ["b"], ["c"]]` a list of single-item lists, as you put in the question? In which case political scientist's one liner should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```py
articles = soup.find_all(class_="quote")
for a in articles:
    list_of_quotes = [] # < shouldn't be inside of a loop
    data = a.find(class_="text")
    quotes = data.get_text()
    list_of_quotes.append(quotes)
```

---

```py
list_of_quotes = []
for a in articles:
    data = a.find(class_="text")
    quotes = data.get_text()
    list_of_quotes.append(quotes)

# or in one line
list_of_quotes = [a.find(class_="text").get_text() for a in articles]

# if you need output as a nested list 
nested_list = [[x] for x in list_of_quotes]
```

```py
# nested_list
[['“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'],
 ['“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”'],
 ['“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”'],
 ['“The person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.”'],
 ["“Imperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.”"],
 ['“Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.”'],
 ['“It is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.”'],
 ["“I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.”"],
 ["“A woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.”"],
 ['“A day without sunshine is like, you know, night.”']]
```